# Graph API Information about Accepting/Declining request made by specific user

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I did a app request trough the new Requests Dialog with GraphAPI.I invited all of my friends that are not using the app. I can get the request_ids as described in the documentation. A can iterate trough all request_ids and see if the request exists. If the user shows up in the app users list it means he accepted the invitation and the request(id) was removed (based on [this link](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=312830#p312830)). The problem is how can I determine that user accepted my request not request from the other user.

e.g. Two users have mutual friend and they both sent him app request the mutual friend accepted the request from the other user so it means he declined mine. Where can I find this information using GraphAPI

I was looking all over the web and I could not find answer.

The point is that need this information in game where I am giving extra time for accepted invitations/requests

Answer (score 0):

You can add data to the app request.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

> data Optional, additional data you may
>   pass for tracking. This will be stored
>   as part of the request objects
>   created.

In there you can add a JSON string containing anything you need, including `{from : user.id }`

So, you can iterate from the request_ids array and check which user sent it.